# Could I use cutout for round images?

Tags: wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig, cutwin

I think if we can use the  cutout for round images, then we don't need to use wrapfig environment.
I know we can use shapedcutout  for circular images but manually by adjust the line length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said with `cutwin` you can define any shape of cutout by manually specifying line lengths. You don't say, but are you after a macro that will (automatically) produce a circular cutout? If so, `cutwin` doesn't provide one.

You could take a look at the `shapepar` package (`> texdoc shapepar`) which shows an example of a cutout for a circular inclusion.

Also on page 101 of the *The TeXbook* Donald Knuth shows an example of a circular inset in a (semi-)circular cutout both specified by using the `\parshape` macro.

Comment: I got the answer from shapepar  manual. by putting shapepar after cutout. "the \cutout \shapepar is cut out (surprise!) to fit the shape"